How to show dynamic content with local notifications in Flutter
I'm currently developing an app that sends to the user a local notification every day at a certain time.
The body of the notification is a String that i randomly pick from a List<String>. The notification gets successfully created with the random String but I can't make it random every time.
The workaround that i found was to schedule a notification and with the onNotificationDisplayedListener re-schedule the same notification the day after with another random String, but obviously it doesn't work in background.
Already tried with the two major plugins for flutter, awesome_notifications and flutter_local_notifications but couldn't make it work with neither of them.
Thank you all!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
